# Xcode Beta 7 Simulator hung on Apple or standard screen, cannot load up my app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I tried to create two view controllers with a segue (just static pngs for now) just to test a build.

Either screen is all black or I get the standard Apple screen (just the regular icons), but don't see my build as a placeholder icon.

I already tried following these recommendations from the Apple Developer Forum and still see no solution. =/

Reinstall the Xcode beta
`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
Open Xcode and delete all the simulators using the Window > Devices window
Take a backup of `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/device_set.plist` and then remove the `com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-0` key. Xcode doesn't seem to put this back so I don't know what else this might break.
Reinstall simulators within Xcode using the + in the lower-left of Window > Devices.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be modifying ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices yourself.  Chances are CoreSimulatorService was running at the time you did that, so you basically changed state out from underneath it.  Where was that recommended to you?  I'd like to comment in that thread so as to not let that information stand.

If you want to erase a device back to its default state, you can use `xcrun simctl erase <UDID>` or just choose the menu item in Simulator.

Now as to your initial problem, when you click on Build & Run, Xcode will install the application and then launch it for you.  If you're not seeing it even install, then there's possibly something going wrong with install.  I suggest you take a look at your device's system.log to see if installation was requested by CoreSimulatorBridge.  If it was, then look for additional log lines that might indicate the failure reason.  If it wasn't, then the issue is on the Xcode side.

Either way, you should file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com including ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/*.log ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/[UDID]/system.log and a sysdiagnose taken when the issue is reproducing.